# Google Domain forward to Digital Ocean linux server, running Apache2 subfolder, and display domain as root

Tags: dns

I've been googling for a bit now, and I really can't seem to figure this out.

I recently bought a domain name with google domains, that I wish to point to a sub domain on my web-server, (example) http://120.0.0.0/sub-folder/, while appearing as domain.com.

Right now I have mbektic.com forwarding to http://138.197.5.88/mbektic/ which kind of gets what I need done, but I wish for the URL to say mbektic.com, instead of the ip address of the server.

Now I've been looking around and I've found things mentioning things from creating records to `.htaccess` files, and honestly I'm completely lost.

If someone could point me to a straightforward guide or give me a list of steps to follow, I can do it myself, but currently I am just lost.

Comment: It's not completely obvious what you want but there's this - https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6072198?hl=en.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to set up external DNS.  You shouldn't need the .htaccess file for what you're doing at all.  The .htaccess file is for directory specific Apache configurations when you need something separate from the global configuration.

There are several providers that will allow you to do this for free, such as CloudFlare, NS1, or Rackspace. Many domain registrars also provide DNS when you register your domain.  I'm not familiar with Google Domains, but it probably offers DNS also.  I'll try to keep this as generic as possible for anyone else looking for this answer.

To do this, pick your DNS provider, set up an account, and take note of the nameservers. Go to the place you registered your domain name and find where you can configure your nameservers and point them to those addresses.  If your registrar also provides DNS, then you can skip this step, as more than likely your nameservers are already configured; just find the DNS configuration on your registrar's website.

Next, you'll configure the DNS. You'll need to create a minimum of two records. The first is an A record and will tell the internet where to find your server (via it's IP address).  It will look like this:

```
A [domain name] [IP address]
```

The second will be your dub address that will redirect www.domain.com to domain.com and then to your IP address.  It will look like this:

```
CNAME www [domain name]
```

Note: there will be a setting on there called TTL, this is the number of seconds that it will take for the old DNS records to be removed from the internet and for your new ones to show up.  Wait at least this long before attempting to troubleshoot any issues.  We call this time period propagation, as the records propagate through the internet.  You'll probably see intermittent results long before you actually get to the TTL, but the records haven't fully propagated until the TTL is reached, so the results will be unstable.

After configuring DNS, when you go to domain.com in your browser, you'll hit your server, but that doesn't mean you'll get to your website. This leads us to the second step, configuring your webserver to accept connections to your website.

The second part of this is a little more complex and will change depending on your server environment. The three big web servers are Apache, Nginx, and IIS. I'm most familiar with Apache, and you've noted that you use that, so I'll give you a very brief example of what you need configured there to make your domain work.

In your apache config, located at /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf or /etc/apache2/conf/apache2.conf, you'll be able to set up a server block. There's a lot of ways to do this, its completely different for each webserver, and there are a lot of options.  I'm going to leave most of those options out here.

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /server/path/to/files/without/mbektic
...other options...
</VirtualHost>
```

*Note: If you have an SSL certificate, then you'll want to set up this exact same server block, but instead of x.x.x.x:80 for your IP, you'll want to use x.x.x.x:443 in your VirtualHost line.  This is not necessary if you don't plan on using HTTPS, but if you configure only 80 or only 443, you will only be able to access the site on http or https.  It's better to do both if you plan on using https, and then redirect from 80 to 443.*

**VirtualHost** = your IP address and the port that you want connections on, port 80 for http traffic and port 443 for https traffic.  For a single website on the server, you can use *:80 instead of x.x.x.x:80.  This gets much more complex when you start adding private IPs and multiple domain names on the same webserver.

**ServerName** = your domain name. This tells your server to accept connections for domain.com to [IP address] on port 80.  Again, his becomes a lot more important when you have multiple domain names and IPs on the webserver.

**ServerAlias** = this is the same thing as ServerName, but gives additional domains to access the same site on. It's an optional line.

**DocumentRoot** = this is the path that the server looks for the files of your website in when a request is made. The reason you don't want to put your subdirectory here is that the domain.com will retrieve files from the document root and domain.com/directory will retrieve files from DocumentRoot/directory.  In this case, I've given you an example that shows you how to get to www.domain.com and to www.domain.com/mbektic.  If you want www.domain.com to go directly to mbektic, then put the full path of that directory as the value of your DocumentRoot.

With these things set up, you should be able to connect to your website with your domain name and get the page that you need to serve.

More information:

- [DNS (specific to Google Domains)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-dns-records-when-your-domain-is-managed-by-google-enom-3c490fbf-7833-4e43-be34-ed0dc3cce5e3)
- [Apache VirtualHost configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, I went and altered the dns records. Going to wait an hour before I continue, but I'll let you know if I run into any issues.